# How to Integrate the D3 charts in Odoo Framework?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I'm Newbie to the Stack,I have facing the issue in odoo,I need to integrate the d3 charts for my model in odoo form view. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,
We need configure the widget in form view Fields in our view.xml file.

**view.xml**

```
<form string="Graph">
                    <field name="name"  widget="test"/>    
</form>
```

Need to create one js file then we need extend the class-openerp.web.form.FieldChar.extend like this,

**D3_chart.js**

```
openerp.transform_organization_chart = function(openerp) {


    openerp.web.form.widgets.add('test','openerp.web.form.test');

    openerp.web.form.test = openerp.web.form.FieldChar.extend(
            {   
                template: 'test-button',

                init: function () {
                    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
                    this._start = null;
                },

                start: function() {
                    console.log('START');
                    this.Myfunction();
                },



                Myfunction: function()

                {   


                }



            });
}
```

Create the template.xml file for our chart,Here we need to write html template.Both template id and Extended Field Character name should be same.

**template.xml**

```
<template id="test-button">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/transform_organization_chart/static/src/js/d3.js"></script>
            <div t-name="test-button">
                <div id="orgChartContainer">
                    <div id="orgChart"></div>
                    </div>
                <div id="consoleOutput"></div>
            </div>
</template>
```

Comment: That code has a tracking code (`_gaq`) so is potentially harmful. You should fix that.